# On integration involving elliptic integral

Tags: definite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

I'm working on the following integral involving an elliptic integral. $E(m)$ is the complete elliptic integral of second kind with parameter $m=k^2$. Is there a way to solve this? Or, is it impossible to expressed in closed form?
$$\int^y_0{\frac{\sqrt{2ax}}{(a+x)^2(a-x)}E\Bigl(\frac{-4ax}{(a-x)^{2}}\Bigl)dx}$$

Comment: You're getting your arguments mixed up: is the argument that in Mathematica or Maple?

Comment: Ah, Mathematica. Sorry for the frustration.

Comment: @JiwooHong Presumably, we can assume that $0<y<a$? Otherwise, the integral is problematic…

Comment: @DavidH Yes, the physical situation where the integral is derived includes $0<y<a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Define the function $\mathcal{I}:\{(a,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\mid0<y<a\}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ via the definite integral

$$\mathcal{I}{\left(a,y\right)}:=\int_{0}^{y}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\sqrt{2ax}}{\left(a+x\right)^{2}\left(a-x\right)}E{\left(-\frac{4ax}{\left(a-x\right)^{2}}\right)},$$

where $E{\left(m\right)}$ is the complete elliptic integral of the second kind, which for our purposes here is defined as a function of the elliptic parameter $m$ by the integral representation

$$E{\left(m\right)}:=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\sqrt{1-mt^{2}}}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}};~~~\small{m\le1}.$$

---

It's not difficult to show that the elliptic integral $E$ obeys the following Landen relation:

$$E{\left(m\right)}=\sqrt{1-m}\,E{\left(\frac{m}{m-1}\right)};~~~\small{m<1}.$$

*Proof*:

$$\begin{align}
E{\left(m\right)}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\sqrt{1-mt^{2}}}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\sqrt{1-m\left(1-t^{2}\right)}}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}};~~~\small{\left[t\mapsto\sqrt{1-t^{2}}\right]}\\
&=\sqrt{1-m}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{m}{m-1}t^{2}}}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}\\
&=\sqrt{1-m}\,E{\left(\frac{m}{m-1}\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

---

Suppose $(a,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\land0<y<a$. Rescaling the parameters of $\mathcal{I}$ as well as the integration variable by the same arbitrary scalar factor $p\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ yields the following result:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(pa,py\right)}
&=\int_{0}^{py}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\sqrt{2pax}}{\left(pa+x\right)^{2}\left(pa-x\right)}E{\left(-\frac{4pax}{\left(pa-x\right)^{2}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{y}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{p\sqrt{2papu}}{\left(pa+pu\right)^{2}\left(pa-pu\right)}E{\left(-\frac{4papu}{\left(pa-pu\right)^{2}}\right)};~~~\small{\left[x=pu\right]}\\
&=p^{-1}\int_{0}^{y}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{\sqrt{2au}}{\left(a+u\right)^{2}\left(a-u\right)}E{\left(-\frac{4au}{\left(a-u\right)^{2}}\right)}\\
&=p^{-1}\mathcal{I}{\left(a,y\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

Hence,

$$\mathcal{I}{\left(a,y\right)}=p\,\mathcal{I}{\left(pa,py\right)};~~~\small{0<y<a\land0<p},$$

and by choosing $p=a^{-1}$ we can automatically set the first parameter to unity:

$$\mathcal{I}{\left(a,y\right)}=a^{-1}\mathcal{I}{\left(1,a^{-1}y\right)};~~~\small{0<a^{-1}y<1}.$$

---

Setting $m=-\frac{4x}{\left(1-x\right)^{2}}$ inside the Landen relation $E{\left(m\right)}=\sqrt{1-m}\,E{\left(\frac{m}{m-1}\right)}$, we have

$$E{\left(-\frac{4x}{\left(1-x\right)^{2}}\right)}=\frac{\left(1+x\right)}{\left(1-x\right)}\,E{\left(\frac{4x}{\left(1+x\right)^{2}}\right)};~~~\small{-1\le x<1}.$$

Then, given $0<z<1$, we have $0<\frac{4z}{(1+z)^{2}}<1$. Setting $b:=\frac{4z}{(1+z)^{2}}$,

we obtain

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(1,z\right)}
&=\int_{0}^{z}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\sqrt{2x}}{\left(1+x\right)^{2}\left(1-x\right)}E{\left(-\frac{4x}{\left(1-x\right)^{2}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{z}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\sqrt{2x}}{\left(1+x\right)^{2}\left(1-x\right)}\cdot\frac{\left(1+x\right)}{\left(1-x\right)}\,E{\left(\frac{4x}{\left(1+x\right)^{2}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{z}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{x}}{\left(1+x\right)\left(1-x\right)^{2}}\,E{\left(\frac{4x}{\left(1+x\right)^{2}}\right)}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{z}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\left(\frac{2\sqrt{x}}{1+x}\right)}{\left(1-x\right)^{2}}\,E{\left(\left(\frac{2\sqrt{x}}{1+x}\right)^{2}\right)}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{\frac{2\sqrt{z}}{1+z}}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{2y}{\left(1+\sqrt{1-y^{2}}\right)^{2}\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}\\
&~~~~~\times\frac{\left(1+\sqrt{1-y^{2}}\right)^{2}y}{4\left(1-y^{2}\right)}\,E{\left(y^{2}\right)};~~~\small{\left[\frac{2\sqrt{x}}{1+x}=y\right]}\\
&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{\frac{2\sqrt{z}}{1+z}}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{u^{2}}{\left(1-u^{2}\right)^{3/2}}\,E{\left(u^{2}\right)};~~~\small{\left[\frac{2\sqrt{x}}{1+x}=u\right]}\\
&=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{\frac{4z}{(1+z)^{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\left(1-x\right)^{3/2}}\,E{\left(x\right)};~~~\small{\left[u=\sqrt{x}\right]}\\
&=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{b}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\left(1-x\right)^{3/2}}\,E{\left(x\right)};~~~\small{\left[b:=\frac{4z}{(1+z)^{2}}\in(0,1)\right]}\\
&=\frac{b\sqrt{b}}{4\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\sqrt{t}}{\left(1-bt\right)^{3/2}}\,E{\left(bt\right)};~~~\small{\left[x=bt\right]}\\
&=\frac{b^{3/2}}{4\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{t^{1/2}E{\left(bt\right)}}{\left(1-bt\right)^{3/2}}.\\
\end{align}$$

---

At this point I'm not sure how to proceed or if this is as simple as it gets. Perhaps there's something to be done with hypergeometrics or maybe *very* clever integration by parts? Anyway, hopefully my answer will be useful to you, if not satisfying. Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you very much, David! The derivations show your enthusiasm on this and are also helpful.